# Wacom (056a:010d) touchscreen is not recognized on Ubuntu 12.10 (64bit)

Tags: 12.10, touchscreen, wacom

I have a Fujitsu Lifebook T902, which has a Wacom 056a:010d touchscreen.

Does anybody know where I could find a driver for this Wacom touchscreen?

Answer (score 1):

```
  apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-wacom
```

Comment: thank you, but xserver-xorg-input-wacom was already installed

Answer (score 0):

Not supported by the driver yet, but thanx to Stephan Frank it works as I described here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2053258&p=12553078#post12553078

Comment: Great, it works :) :) :)

Comment: A big thank you and of course Stephan Frank for this job!!! I'd like to reciprocate! How can I do it?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the 'xorg' process causes constantly a cpu load of 100% when I create all as described in link above. If the 'wacom' line was disabled in the /etc/modules file and the notebook restarted, a cpu load would decreased to a value of view percents. But the touch display was konsequently disabled. Do you have any idea, what is wrong with 'xorg' if I enable touch display?

Comment: Sorry, I have no such issues with it whatsoever, it just works perfectly. Did you try a clean install?